# Add a value from a column in one table based off finding a result in another in R

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics

I have a data table in R:

```
  |gene           |   prom_65|   prom_66|  amast_69|  amast_70|  markerID|
  |:--------------|---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:| 
  |ABC            |   24.7361|   25.2550|   31.2974|45.4209   |16:123234_T/C; 16:54352342_A/T; 16:747564_T/G|
  |DFG            |  107.3580|  112.9870|   77.4182|   86.3211| 16:3453453_G/A; 16:765753453_A/T; 16:65345345_T/G| 
  |LKP            |   72.0639|   86.1486|   68.5747|   77.8383| 16:25234453_G/C; 16:876456546_A/T; 16:4535_T/G| 
  |KLF            |   43.8766|   53.4004|   34.0255|   38.4038| 16:87484_G/A; 16:5435_A/T; 16:747564_T/G|  
  |PPO            | 2382.8700| 1871.9300| 2013.4200| 2482.0600| 16:785_T/C; 16:5435_A/T; 16:747564_T/G| 
  |LWPV           |   49.6488|   53.7134|   59.1175|   66.0931| 16:123_T/C; 16:54564_A/T; 16:54646_T/G|
```

I have another data table:

```
|markerid       |   prom_65|   prom_66|  amast_69|  amast_70|  pvalue|
|:--------------|---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|
|16:123234_T/C |x         |     x    |       x  |       x  |     x    |
|16:3453453_G/A|  x       |    x     |     x            x  |       x  |
```

I would like to add the gene column to table two for the markerid that matches the relevant gene in table one. In table one the markerIDs are all separated by a semi-colon and a markerID will only ever appear within one gene row in table1. In this example the output should look like this:

```
|markerid       |   prom_65|   prom_66|  amast_69|  amast_70|  pvalue  |gene|
|:--------------|---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|
|16:123234_T/C  |x         |     x    |       x  |       x  |     x    |ABC
|16:3453453_G/A |  x       |    x     |     x    |        x |       x  |DFG
```

Not sure how to approach this in R.

Many thanks

Comment: can you add`dput` of your dataset?

Comment: Apologies @jyjek I work within a airlock environment so have to manually type out the table. I cannot copy/past information out.

Comment: it's very hard to reproduce. Try to use `tidyr::separate_rows(markerID)` for first table and join after this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a reproducible example of your table, it is hard to be sure what looks like the last column (it seems to be a list but not sure).

You can try on the second table:

```r
Table2$gene <- sapply(Table2$markerid, function(x) Table1$Gene[grep(x,Table1$marker_id)])
```

Here an example with dummy dataframes:

```r
dataA <- data.frame(Gene = LETTERS[1:5], 
                    marker = paste(letters[6:10],"_A"))

  Gene marker
1    A   f _A
2    B   g _A
3    C   h _A
4    D   i _A
5    E   j _A
```

```r
dataB <- data.frame(marker = letters[6:8])
  marker
1      f
2      g
3      h
```

And now, if you use the `sapply` function:

```r
dataB$Gene <- sapply(dataB$marker, function(x) dataA$Gene[grep(x,dataA$marker)])

1      f    A
2      g    B
3      h    C
```

Does it look what you are trying to get ?

If it is not working, can you provide the output of `str(Table1)` ?

Comment: It does and it worked perfectly on my dataset! May thanks for taking the time to answer and apologies for not being able to export my dataset. I'll go read up on sapply now!